# signTransaction for SMS

Tags: anchor, wallet, mobile

I am trying to interact with an Anchor project on the solana mobile stack. I have gotten the example app working and have messed around with the fakewallet/fakedapp. I want to use the AnchorWallet in order to sign transactions, but it requires the signTransaction field, which is missing on mobile.

I just used the wallet: WalletContextState and wallet.provider to do this for web. I also don't exactly understand all the caching done on the example.

*This is the mobile code. The web code is exactly the same, but wallet is of type Web3MobileWallet.*

[image]

*We need the getProvider() function so that we can make getProgram() to find the Anchor Program. This is the web function here:*
[image]

Comment: Can you hone your question down to 1) what you’ve tried, and 2) where you got stuck (ie. where you expected `signTransaction` to be available but it wasn’t)? Specifics and code samples will help here.

Comment: @steveluscher Hey, just added the exact code snippets for the implementation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The raw `mobile-wallet-adapter-protocol-web3js` module that you’ve imported does not export a `signTransactions` method. The only method that it exports is a `transact` method. See more on how to use the raw protocol [here](https://github.com/solana-mobile/mobile-wallet-adapter/tree/main/js/packages/mobile-wallet-adapter-protocol#quick-start).

You might be interested, instead, in the wallet adapter plugin [`@solana-mobile/wallet-adapter-mobile`](https://github.com/solana-mobile/mobile-wallet-adapter/tree/main/js/packages/wallet-adapter-mobile) which *does* offer an interface closer to what you expect.